# Find the coefficient of $x$ in the given polynomial

Tags: polynomials, binomial-theorem

We have polynomial
$$(x-2^0)(x-2^1)(x-2^2)···(x-2^n)$$
I know that the coefficient of $x$ equals to:
$$(-1)^{n-1}((2^0×2^1×···×2^{n-1})+(2^0×2^1×···×2^{n})+···+(2^1×2^2×···×2^{n}))$$

But it's hard to calculate this sum.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This coefficient is the product of the product of the roots and the sum of their reciprocals, with the appropriate sign.

Comment: @Mindlack Why is the coefficient product of the product of the roots and the sum of their reciprocals?

Comment: Just compute what this makes (ignoring the actual value of the roots). Basically, when you expand, each reciprocal will make you compute the product, without one term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of $x$ in $(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ is
$$
(-1)^n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_1 \cdots a_n}{a_k}
$$
If $a_k=2^{k-1}$, then $a_1 \cdots a_n = 2^0 2^1 \cdots 2^{n-1} = 2^{0+1+\cdots +(n-1)}=2^{n(n-1)/2}$.

Thus, the coefficient is
$$
(-1)^n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{n(n-1)/2}}{2^{k-1}}
=
(-1)^n 2^{n(n-1)/2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}
= \cdots
$$

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A127850

Comment: Great! Can the last expression simplified even more?

Comment: @Lanet, sure, it's a geometric series.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot.